# jQuery Masonry positioning issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I used jQuery Masonry for the first time. And just crashing my head on my computer that what it is displaying me.

I have jQuery as follows:

```
$("#box-container").masonry({
    itemSelector: ".box",
    columnWidth: 100
});
```

CSS:

```
#content #left-content #box-container .box {
   width:280px;
   height:auto;
   margin:18px 0 0 18px;
   background:#fafafa;
   position:relative;
   min-width:230px;
   float:left;
}
```

HTML, I think is not needed.

**ISSUE:**

I applied all this stuff. Included jQuery Masonry. All fine but when I refreshed my document. What I see?

All the `div`s are on above of each other. But I thought may be there will be error in console indicating the type of error. So, I can fix it.

When I clicked "Inspect Element", I was surprised to see that all `div`s got set as required. But why it does not do on page load?
I am making Basic Multi-column layout. Is any style interfering?

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle for this?

Comment: Just wait i think I can :D

Comment: @John i think , its working in fiddle but not in my document. http://jsfiddle.net/b8FyE/

Comment: @John have you used it ? Maybe I haven't done correctly

Comment: How do you want to look?

Comment: @John that was timing problem. IDK why. But i used `setTimeout` and its working.

Answer (score 1):

A setTimeout function might work on some case, but the best solution is to wait for images to load before calling Masonry, like that :

```
$(window).load(function(){
  // Call Masonry here
});
```

So it will wait for all content on window to load, before calculating position of each items.
SetTimeout may work now, but you surely have the same issue if your content takes more than 1 seconde to be loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by just adding `setTimeout` function.

```
setTimeout( function() {
  $("#box-container").masonry({
      itemSelector: ".box",
      columnWidth: 100
  });
}, 1000);
```

Comment: I was able to get by with a timeout of 100.